# Why can't some functions be used in kernel modules?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

For examples, in `pgtable_types.h`, the function prototype:

```
extern pte_t *lookup_address(unsigned long address, unsigned int *level);
```

Is clearly present in the header file.

However when I compile a kernel module with this function and then insmod the `.ko` output file I get a `lookup_address` symbol not found error.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your module have a `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2")` line in it? If not, it is assumed to be proprietary and will not allow access to GPL symbols which `lookup_address` is marked as.